# Selecting specific node using XPATH

Tags: xpath

I have simple XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <date>BBB</date>
  <name>CCC</name>
</root>
```

I need to select name value "CCC", by date value "BBB".It works fine for next XPATH:

`/root[date=BBB]/name`

But as long as i have namespace declared i can not upper XPATH. 
For this case i know it is possible to use local-name() function. But if i write next expression

`/*[local-name() = 'root[date=BBB]']/*/*[local-name() = 'name']`

It does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing any QName test for `*[local-name()='...']` in

```
/root[date='BBB']/name
```

You should use:

```
/*[local-name() = 'root'][*[local-name()='date']='BBB']
  /*[local-name() = 'name']
```

But for this case I would use:

```
/*[*[local-name()='date']='BBB']/*[local-name() = 'name']
```

A little shorter with a "whatever root element".